# Yfinance module stopped working randomly?

Tags: python, yfinance

Myself and a few classmates have been working on a project for the passed few days. We use yfinance package in the project to get stock data. All of a sudden, today, we can not use get_open_price() anymore. We are met with an error code every time we try. I have been trying to resolve the issue for hours with no luck since the project is due tonight. I have tried: updating yfinance, uninstalling/reinstalling yfinance, installing and using an old version of yfinance. Does anyone know how we can solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: How much have you been querying? You are limited to 2,000 requests per hour per IP on the public endpoint

Comment: as far as i understand this is a 3rd party service, and Yahoo is free to adjust their API as desired which could feasibly break that module. ok here's the official wording: "yfinance is not affiliated, endorsed, or vetted by Yahoo, Inc. It's an open-source tool that uses Yahoo's publicly available APIs, and is intended for research and educational purposes." from https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.